# Assembly Mips replace "and" with rotation and shift commands

Tags: assembly, mips

Is there a way to swap "and" command with only rotation and shift commands in the following lines of code? I'd like it to work with any input, not just with this one. Any help is appreciated.

```
        .text
        .globl __start
__start:
        la $a0,Input
        lw $t1,0($a0)
        li $t0, 0x001FF800
        and $t2, $t1, $t0
        li $v0,10
        syscall
        .data
input:            .word 0x12345678
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to *X and Y* the trick is **selectively clear** any given bit of X based on the correspondingly bit of Y.

Let assume *X* and *Y* are 4 bit numbers with each bit named with a letter

```
X = aBcd
Y = dEfg
```

We are computing the *AND* between their 3rd bits *B* and *E* respectively.

**NOTA BENE** that in my notation the lsb is the first bit.

Let's call *i* the bit index (starting from 0), in this example `i = 2` and *n* the number of bits, in this case `n = 4`.

The *AND* can be performed in four steps.

**1. Bring the *B* bit to the "front", i.e. as the lsb of *X***

We do this with a **rotation** to the right.

```
X = ROR(X, i)
X = cdaB
```

**Note** MIPS doesn't support rotation, you can however easily emulate them.

**2. Isolate *E* bit and bring it to the "front"**

In order to do this without any *AND* we first shift (a copy of) Y to the right, then to the left

```
Y' = SHL(Y, n-1-i)
Y' = Efg0

Y' = SHR(Y', n-1-i)
Y' = 0Efg

Y' = SHR(Y', i)
Y' = 000E
```

**3. Zero the *B* bit if Y' is zero**

Now if Y' is zero, the *B* bit, the lsb of X, must be cleared. To do this, without *AND*s we can shift *X* to the right by 1 and then shift it back to the left.

```
If Y' == 0 Then
   X = SHR(X, 1)
   X = 0cda
   X = SHL(X, 1)
   X = cda0
End If
```

If *Y'* is not 0, then *X* is left unchanged.
We note that now the lsb of *X* is the *AND* between *B* and *E*, we can call this value *Z* and write *X* as follow:

```
X = cdaZ
```

4. Rotate *X* back

We rotate *X* back

```
X = ROL(X, i)
X = aZcd
```

**If we compute this four steps for every i = 0..n-1 we get the *AND* between *X* and *Y*.**

---

Here the relative MIPS code tested with MARS

```
#$a0 = op1  $a1 = op2

add $v0, $0, $a0

ori $t0, $0, 31
ori $t1, $0, 1
add $t5, $0, $0

#$t0 = Counter
#$t1 = 32-Counter

PerformAnd:
    #$t4 = ror $t4, $a0, $t1
    add $t3, $0, $v0
    srlv $t3, $t3, $t0
    add $t4, $0, $v0
    sllv $t4, $t4, $t1
    or $t4, $t4, $t3

    #$t3 = isolate bit $t0 of $a1
    add $t3, $0, $a1
    sllv $t3, $t3, $t5
    srlv $t3, $t3, $t5
    srlv $t3, $t3, $t0

    bnez $t3, InverseROL

    srl $t4, $t4, 1
    sll $t4, $t4, 1   #Clear lsb of $t4

InverseROL:
    add $t3, $0, $t4
    sllv $t3, $t3, $t0
    srlv $t4, $t4, $t1
    or $v0, $t4, $t3  

    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    addi $t5, $t5, 1
    subi $t0, $t0, 1
    bgez $t0, PerformAnd
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any rotate instructions in the MIPS instruction set <sup><sub>(ok, [apparently there is](https://cloud.github.com/downloads/paul99/v8m-rb/MD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-03.01.pdf) on some implementations)</sub></sup>. Assuming that you have some way of rotating a register, the following code does an `AND`-less `AND` operation that should work for any 32-bit input. I'll leave it to you to implement the algorithm in MIPS assembly.

```c
unsigned u    = 0x12345678;
unsigned mask = 0x001FF800;
unsigned mask_count = 0;

while (mask_count < 32) {
    // Keep bits in u where the corresponding bit in the mask is a 1
    // The shifts in the while-expression are used to avoid an AND for checking the lsb
    while ((((mask >> 1) << 1) != mask) && mask_count < 32) {
        mask >>= 1;
        u = ror(u, 1);
        mask_count++;
    }
    // Clear bits in u where the corresponding bit in the mask is a 0
    while ((((mask >> 1) << 1) == mask) && mask_count < 32) {
        mask >>= 1;
        u >>= 1;
        mask_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rotate instructions (`ROTR` and `ROTRV`) were added in the MIPS32R2 ISA release.

Comment: No problem! I just wanted to correct the record for future googlers.